# Codeigniter basepath issue on xampp

Tags: apache, codeigniter, xampp

I've been working in a local dev environment for some time now with Codeigniter v1.7.1, and I recently installed xampp to replace it. Before, I had modified my hosts file and added a the virtualhost in my httpd.conf file, and my website was running at dev.mysite.com.

After installing xampp, the html is displaying when I go to the url localhost/mysite, however, none of the paths are working correctly, because they are formatted relative to the site root, which apparently is not being set correctly.

For instance:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/public_scripts/homepage.js"></script>`
is pointing toward the URL localhost/public_scripts rather than localhost/mysite/public_scripts.

I went into config.php and changed the base_url to a number of different things, such as mysite/, but nothing worked.

What can I do to get CI to use localhost/mysite as the root, so that relative paths formatted like /public_scripts/script.js use mysite as the base url and not localhost?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your hosts file (C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) add

```
127.0.0.1   dev.mysite.com
```

In your [virtual host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#virtualhost) file for that site check the DocumentRoot has 'mysite' in it
c:\xampp\apache\conf\extra\mysite.com.conf

```
DocumentRoot C:/path_to_my_website/site/www/htdocs/mysite/
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you tons! Also, I found in the xampp Apache http folder, another folder called "extras" which has a file included by the httpd.conf file, which is where you can add the virtualhosts. Once that was in there, it started working flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the base_url in your views?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url()?>public_scripts/homepage.js"></script>
```

Comment: The base_url is not being used in my views, just src="/public_scripts/...".

Comment: Then change it to the code I posted above and put `http:/localhost/mysite/` as your base URL in the config file. You'll need to autoload the `url`-helper.

Comment: Thank you, but there must be a way around having to do that, because this is a large scale development project that I inherited, and it is working everywhere else. It would take hours to go through and change all relative links on the website to include the basepath.

Comment: I'll second this: if you use links like `src="/public_scripts/` (instead of `src="public_scripts`) you are explicitly saying **start at the root of the domain** (using absolute urls, not relative urls). You will need to put the base_url call to get the links to properly resolve root urls to anywhere other than `localhost` (or you will need to use mod_rewrite or something similar to redirect those requests).

Comment: After Femi's comment, I looked at the .htaccess file on the server and found this: `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L] `...

Comment: but after including that htaccess file in my local environment, still no affect.

Answer (score 0):

This is just about your /etc/hosts and xampp httpd conf file - you must set up mapping 127.0.0.1 dev.mysite.local or whatever the local domain should be and then add virtualhost like you did before, no way to do this in CI or .htacces.